# error in display swipe view

Tags: android, android-listview

this is my grid view and by click item of Grid View i am try to pass position of item to display in full screen swipe view....next 'FullscreenimageActivity class' will invoke..............

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) m1Context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
        View customRow1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gview, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) customRow1
                .findViewById(R.id.imageforgrid);
       switch (gotbread) {
        case 0:
            image.setImageResource(images2[position]);
            break;
        case 1:
            image.setImageResource(images1[position]);
            break;
        }
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleX((float) 0.5);
        image.setScaleY((float) 0.5);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return customRow1;
    }
}
class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // on selecting grid view image
        // launch full screen activity
        Intent i = new Intent(Customgrid.this, FullScreenImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("position", _postion);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

this is 'FullscreenimageActivity class' to set image in swipe view..

```
public class FullScreenImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_view);
    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    Fullscreenimage adapter = new Fullscreenimage(
            FullScreenImageActivity.this);

    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

}

this is adapter class for full screen swipe view image......

```
public class Fullscreenimage extends PagerAdapter {
public Integer[] images1 = { R.drawable.s_1, R.drawable.s_2, R.drawable.s_3 };

public Context mContext;


public Fullscreenimage(Context context) {
    super();
    this.mContext = context;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    View viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_view,
            container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) viewlayout
            .findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    imageview.setImageResource(images1[position]);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewlayout, 0);
    return viewlayout;
}
```

}

by click this image it should show full screen image..

[image]

instant of showing full image it showing just blank screen...plz help me.

[image]

Comment: So are you getting any error/exception?

Comment: there are no exception or error...but is is not showing image ..it just showing screen.

Comment: In `getCount` method try returning the length of the `images1` array `@Override
 public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return images1.length;
}`

Comment: still it's not working ...bro..plz help out..

Comment: First just check it out are you getting correct index value.